# Paste Value only In Excel VBA code with "find" function

Tags: excel, vba

How do I further modify the code so that it just paste the values only on my "Cable_List" worksheet rather than formula from the "Data" sheets.

```
Dim strLastRow As String
Dim rngC As Range
Dim strToFind As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim wSht As Worksheet
Dim rngtest As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wSht = Worksheets("Data")
With wSht.Range("BM:BM")
    Set rngC = .Find(What:="PVC", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = rngC.Address
        Do
            strLastRow = Sheets("Cable List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            rngC.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Cable List").Cells(strLastRow, 1) 'part where copy and paste was done
            Set rngC = .FindNext(rngC)
        Loop While Not rngC Is Nothing And rngC.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

Credits: sarasotavince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
rngC.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Cable List").Cells(strLastRow, 1)
```

to this:

```
rngC.EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Cable List").Cells(strLastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: wow, thanks man, that did nice on what I needed, appreciate much! :D